# How do I display data fetched from firestore to a boostrap table in reactjs? I'm able to fetch but cannot display with the standard way of doing it

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from the firestore and display it to a bootstrap table with reactjs.I'm able to get the data and store it in a map, and I can even console with developer tools and see it. However, when it comes to displaying it to the table, I'm using the proper way of looping the map and populate it but It cannot display anything. I need help.

```
    constructor(){
    super();
       this.state={
         mydata=[]
      }
     }
    getUsers=async()=>{
    console.log("hello");
    await firebaseapp.firestore().collection('users').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      //console.log(snapshot);
      snapshot.forEach((doc,key) => {

        mydata.push({username:doc.data().username,group:doc.data().group,email:doc.data().email});

      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });


   }



    render(){
         return(
       <Paper className={styles.root}>
       <Table className={styles.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell  className={styles.tableCell}>username</TableCell>
            <TableCell  className={styles.tableCell}>email</TableCell>
           <TableCell  className={styles.tableCell}>group</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
              {mydata.map((data,key)=>{
                 return(
                  <TableRow >
                  <TableCell  className={styles.tableCell}>{data.username}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell  className={styles.tableCell}>{data.group}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell  className={styles.tableCell}>{data.emails}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                 )
              })  
              }

        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>

          )
    }
     componentDidMount(){
       this.getUsers();
     }
```

Comment: Are you able to console.log `mydata` after you push the values to it? I think you need to access it using `this.state`

Comment: please see the instruction of state in the [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use the state variable so, it can't redraw when you get the data.
try like this.

```
...
    constructor(){
    super();
       this.state={
         mydata: []
      }
     }
...
      let data = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc,key) => {
          data.push({username:doc.data().username,group:doc.data().
                  group,email:doc.data().email});
      });
     this.setState({mydata: data});
...
  render() {
    const { mydata } = this.state;
   ...
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, man. It works very well as I wanted it to.That's good.